com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException
I have weird issue where json deserialization fails only in production and not in lower environments
It gives invalidtypeid exception
**
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [map type; class java.util.HashMap, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class java.lang.Object]]: missing type id property '@class'**
Sprint boot 2.7.17
Can any one help how can we start debugging issue as I did not see in lower environments

Have you tried comparing the JSON strings between the environments?
Perhaps the data in the lowers were destroyed and recreated with the @class fields, but in production they weren't, but the code was modified to add @JsonTypeInfo after the data in production was created, now causing this error on deserialisation?
